# MacOS (Big Sur) Image Capure - How to change default "Import To" directory/folder?

Tags: macos, big-sur, image-capture

In MacOS Big Sur (and above) whenever I launch Image Capture the "Import To" dropdown always defaults to "Pictures".

[image]

I would like to change this to always default to my "Downloads" directory.

With previous versions of MacOS I had been able to change this default value but since upgrading to Big Sur the value has changed back to "Pictures" and I've been unable to make a permanent change to the app.

Comment: It ought to retain a location per device. If you’re copying from an SD for instance, it will be considered a ‘new’ device each time it’s reformatted (which many seem to do frequently for camera SDs)

Comment: @Tetsujin it does not. I am regularly importing from my iPhone (the same device) and everytime Image Capture restarts its reset to "Pictures".

Comment: Hmm, OK. I can't test for Big Sur, so I hope someone finds what's wrong. Wish you luck.